# Apt complains of missing public keys, even though the keys are added

Tags: apt, updates, gnupg

In Ubuntu 20.04.4, when running `sudo apt update` the update does not retrieve all packages reporting this error:

> An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA071 NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB

I have already added the specified public keys with these commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FEEA9169307EA071
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
```

and I can see the keys in the "Authentication" tab of the apt settings:
[image]

but still the error remains.

I have tried removing the two keys and adding them again, but it makes no difference. I have also disabled all "Other Software" repositories.

Without being able to run `apt update` I'm unable to upgrade to the latest release

### Aditional:

Since I'm aiming to upgrade distribution, I don't need third party repositories enabled. When I run `apt update` I see, in addition to the standard Ubuntu repositiories, it is looking for updates from

- https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease

and also

- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease (which doesn't fail)

but I can't see why. I have deselected everything in the "Other Software" tab of "Software & Updates" and also checked in
`/etc/apt/sources.list` which only has Ubuntu repositories un-commented.

How can I get `apt update` to ignore these third party repositories?

Comment: To upgrade to the latest release, no third party software center should be active anyway. So inactivate them all, then you will be able to full-upgrade and then upgrade to the newer Ubuntu version.

Comment: @vanadium you're right that https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt is a third party repository and there's another third party repo that is hit in the apt update. I have unchecked all entries under "Other software" and also checked in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but can't find these repositories. I'll extend the question.

Comment: Check also the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d, where any file ending with the `.list` or `.source` extension is also declaring a source.